# Simple combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n_{1},n_{2},\ldots,n_{m}$ be a finte number of positive integers. Let $n=\sum_{i=1}^{m}n_{i}$. Let $k$ be a positive integer such that $1\leq k\leq m$.

Let $n_{i}$ be the number of identical objects of type $i$, $i=1,2\ldots m$.

The objects of typ $n_{i}$ and $n_{j}$ are distinct for all different $i$ and $j$.

In how many ways can i pick distinct collections of $k$ objects, with respect to order, from the totalt $n$ objects?

Comment: may be you meant $k$ distinct objects, right? otherwise the answer would be the number of permutations of length $k$.

Comment: Thats right @rak

Comment: I guess you'll have better chances to get your question answered if you've included your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: This is a generalization of a particular question i got. I have forgotten all about combinatorics and just wanted to see a general formula. @rak

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution uses [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).
Assuming we are counting *ordered* sequences of $k$ objects (e.g. if $k=3$, the outcomes ABB and BAB are distinct), then the answer is the coefficient of $x^k/k!$ in the product
$$\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{x^{n_1}}{n_1!}\right)
\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+ \frac{x^{n_2}}{n_2!}\right)\cdots
\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+ \frac{x^{n_m}}{n_m!}\right)
$$

On the other hand, if you wanted to count *unordered* sequences of $k$ objects (so that ABB and BAB represent the same outcome), the answer is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the product
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&(1+x+x^2+\cdots x^{n_1}) (1+x+x^2+\cdots x^{n_2})\cdots(1+x+x^2+\cdots x^{n_m})\\
=&\frac{(1-x^{n_1+1})(1-x^{n_2+1})\cdots(1-x^{n_m+1})}{(1-x)^m}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: So it's the ordered sequences i'm interested in. Could you provide me with a small proof? @tad

Comment: Exponential generating functions are a standard tool in combinatorics.  There are many references online, but Ed Bender's notes represent an especially accessible exposition for non-specialists.  Your problem is essentially Example 11.6.  See http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ebender/CombText/ch-11.pdf